# How to check if OrientDB server is creating/rebuilding indecies?

Tags: java, orientdb

We need to check in client app if OrientDB is creating or rebuilding indecies. During this procedure server is very slow on processing CRUD operations from client and it leads to huge problems.

Is there any way to check?

Answer (score 1):

To see if the rebuild is running or not you can took a look on the server log and you should see something like this:

[image]

During the rebuild, any idempotent queries made against the index, skip the index and perform sequential scans. This means that queries run slower during this operation. Non-idempotent commands, such as `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` are blocked waiting until the indexes are rebuilt.

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Is it possible to do this check using API? @Michela Bonizzi